# App Engine Data store understanding no Sql

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have these 2 Data Stores:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.EmailProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    image = db.LinkProperty(required = True)

class Post(db.Model):
    post = db.StringProperty(required = True, multiline = True)
    submitter = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    receiver = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

However the problem is then I generate a user page where I'm displaying all the posts the user received but I'm doing this in a very SQL and naive fashion like so:

```
ret = []
    #Get all Posts
    for p in self.getPosts():
        #If the receiver of the post is equal to uId
        if str(p.receiver) == str(uId):

            #Get submitter Details
            sDetails = self.getUserDetails(p.submitter)

            #Check that details were received
            if sDetails:
                #Add needed Details to post
                p.sName = sDetails.name
                p.sId = str(sDetails.key().id())
                p.sImage = sDetails.image

                ret.append(p)
    return ret
```

How would you guys improve this? The thing I'm hating most in this approach is having to go through each post which will result in the system being extremely slow once the system gets bigger.

Also please note that all posts are stored in memcache therefor I can't use GQL to make this better. Unless you have a better idea for storing stuff in memcache rather then my approach... Which is, to chuck all frequently used queries in there and update the cache once a new item to the datastore is added.

For those that maybe are following a bit my questions this project is a new concept to social media and will post a link once it's done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't get all the posts from the database each time; use a filter query to get all posts matching a specific user id:

```
q = db.Query(Post)
q.filter('receiver =', uId)
```

If you can't do this at the moment because you're storing every single post under one memcache key, maybe you should adjust your approach — it probably won't scale well. Using a query such as that above, you can take advantage of the GAE datastore's indexing and query functionality, which will always outperform directly iterating through an entire entity set in your application.

I'd suggest storing user pages in memcache *after* you've generated them from the datastore.

Also, on `Post`, you can use `db.ReferenceProperty` for `submitter` and `receiver`:

```
class Post(db.Model):
post = db.StringProperty(required = True, multiline = True)
submitter = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=User, required = True)
receiver = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=User, required = True)
created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty

Comment: Hmm interesting. I like this approach a lot! The only thing I have a little doubt on is; When creating a new post what type of data should I put in the referenceProperty? Just an int with an id of the user or a whole user object?

Comment: @DylanGrech

The whole user object.